# express http client connect to server , https client can't connect to server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, certbot

I've made a server that works with http just fine. The server was up and I was able to connect to it with Chrome and Postman. When I switch the server to https, the server is up, but I can't connect to it with Chrome and Postman. the ssl keys were sign by certbot.

server.js

```
const https = require('https');
const app = require(__dirname+'/app');
const fs = require('fs');

const port = 80;
const options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync("ssl/v2/fullchain.pem"),
    key: fs.readFileSync("ssl/v2/privkey.pem")
}

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
console.log(port);
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const body_parser = require('body-parser');

const homepage = require(__dirname+'/routes/homepage');
const user = require(__dirname+'/routes/user');
const test = require(__dirname+'/routes/test');
const table = require(__dirname+'/routes/table');
const catalog = require(__dirname+'/routes/catalog');
const cart = require(__dirname+'/routes/cart');
const payment = require(__dirname+'/routes/payment');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(body_parser.json());
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use("/", homepage);
app.use("/user", user);
app.use("/test", test);;
app.use("/table", table);
app.use("/catalog", catalog);
app.use("/cart", cart);
pp.use("/payment", payment);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the server is up, but I can't connect to it with Chrome and Postman

It is not clear from your description **how exactly** you are trying to connect to the server but I assume that you'll try a simple `https://example.com/`.

```
const port = 80;
...
https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
```

But based on your code you are trying to use HTTPS on the port reserved for plain HTTP (80) instead of using the default port for HTTPS (443). Thus, `https://example.com/` will not work since this will try to use port 443 and you would need to explicitly specify a different port with `https://example.com:80/`. But the better option would of course to use the default port for HTTPS in the first place in your code, i.e. 443 instead of 80.

Comment: this work, I didn't realize that http and https have 2 different default ports. I feel like an idiot now.